# react native : what is the way to change class component to function component in my example?

Tags: reactjs, function, react-native, react-hooks

what is the way to change class component to function component in my example ?
in my example i try to change it to a function component but it doesnt works ,
I would be happy to some help with this issue .

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    firstQuery: '',
  };

  render() {
    const { firstQuery } = this.state;
    return (
      <Searchbar
      style={{marginTop: 60}}
        placeholder="Search"
        onChangeText={query => { this.setState({ firstQuery: query }); }}
        value={firstQuery}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of your attempt to convert your class-based component to a functional component. What do you do with the `firstQuery` state other than update it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import  React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';

const MyComponent =()=> {
  const [firstQuery, setFirstQuery] = useState("");

    return (
      <Searchbar
      style={{marginTop: 60}}
        placeholder="Search"
        onChangeText={query => { setFirstQuery(query ) }}
        value={firstQuery}
      />
    );
  
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [firstQuery, setFirstQuery] = useState('');
  
  const _onChange = query => setFirstQuery(query); 
  
  return (
    <Searchbar
      style={{marginTop: 60}}
      placeholder="Search"
      onChangeText={_onChange}
      value={firstQuery}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [firstQuery, setFirstQuery] = useState('');
  
  const handleChange = (query) => setFirstQuery(query); 
  
  return (
    <Searchbar
      style={{marginTop: 60}}
      placeholder="Search"
      onChangeText={handleChange}
      value={firstQuery}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';

const MyComponent = (props) => { 

  const [firstQuery, setFirstQuery] = React.useState(''); 
     
    return (
     <Searchbar
        style={{marginTop: 60}}
        placeholder="Search"
        onChangeText={query => { setFirstQuery(query) }}
        value={firstQuery}
      />
    );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
//Only get what we need to reduce overhead
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Searchbar } from "react-native-paper";

//you may include props here if needed, otherwise = () =>
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  
  //State as hook, first object in array will be value second will be function to set value and notify update required
  const [firstQuery, setFirstQuery] = useState("");
  
  //handle for onChangeText
  const onChangeTextHandle = (query) => {
    //set state using hook
    setFirstQuery(query);
  };

  //No need for render method, just return JSX
  return (
    <Searchbar
      style={{ marginTop: 60 }}
      placeholder="Search"
      onChangeText={onChangeTextHandle}
      value={firstQuery}
    />
  );
};

//Export component Here
export default MyComponent;
```